# Conditional Implicit Definitions Scala

Tags: scala, implicit, inferred-type

I have to solve this quinz but i can't find the correct answer.

```
trait Physics {
  implicit def air: Gaz,
  implicit def condense(implicit gaz: Gaz): Liquid,
  implicit def freeze(implicit liquid: Liquid): Solid

  implicitly[Solid]
}
```

Can you rewrite the last line with the inferred parameter explicitly written?

Hint: It should look like 
implicitly[Solid](...

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's from coursera quiz, right?

Comment: Yes, but even after rereading the documentation I can't find the correct solution

Comment: Shouldn't they be done on one's own?

Comment: I also spent an hour to understand what that question means. Another hint: put things in order, and remove any space.

Comment: Hey Dmytro, could you please share the solution please?

Comment: implicitly[Solid](freeze(condense(air)))

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hint: first consider `implicitly` is just a method like any other

```
def implicitly[T](implicit e: T): T = e
```

Lets remove the keyword `implicit` such that

```
def implicitly[T](e: T): T = e
```

Given `implicitly` is just a method taking arguments, think about what would you have to do to make compiler happy and have method `implicitly` return a `Solid`?